# Why was NVIDIA NvFBCHWEncode interface deprecated starting with NVIDIA Capture SDK 5.0.?

Tags: encoding, nvidia, capture, framebuffer, nvenc

I've been working on a project that requires capturing and streaming video content from backend applications and headless chromium/browsers. So far I was able to do so by calling the older version of NVIDIA Capture SDK for capturing from GPU framebuffer and directly encoding using the NVENC interface in the SDK. Then stream the encoded frames with ffmpeg libraries.

However, when upgrading the SDK to > 5.0 version or the NVIDIA driver to 510 version. It no longer worked because NVIDIA has deprecated the NvFBCHWEncode interface without a good alternative. I'm been doing lots of researches and couldn't find why NVIDIA decided to do so. Could anyone help answering this or providing viable alternatives? Thanks!

The project must run on Linux and must programmatically capture, encode and stream videos.

Tried doing researches extensively but could not find the answer.

Comment: Please share more details. Did you try to ask the maintainers of that SDK for such information?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have read through the Capture SDK and Codec SDK documentations but couldn't find a clue. I suppose asking here is more efficient than asking NVIDIA directly?

Comment: Why should anybody here know abot that? If NVIDIA provides that SDK, their developers should know best why they deprecate something